# Action console asking for "app information" for "smart home app" and no "actions" listed under "actions added from actions SDK"

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a project for smart home app. My action package is like this:

```
{
  "actions": 
  [
    {
      "name": "actions.devices",
      "fulfillment": 
      {
          "conversationName": "automation"
      }
    }
  ],

  "conversations": 
  {
      "automation": 
      {
        "name": "automation",
        "url": "endpoint url here"
      }
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is for smart home. But I am still asked to fill in the pronounciation for the app name in the app information. This is weird, because a smart home app doesn't need to be called like talk to Blah Blah Blah. You just need to enable it under home control > add devices. So, why do I need to fill in the pronounciation? Does this mean the action console didn't recognized it as a smart home app?

Another thing is, I don't have any actions listed under Actions added from actions sdk. Is this the normal for smart home app? The docs didn't explain that much so I really don't know what really is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both of these behaviors are expected. You should be able to register your devices with the Google Home app and then control them with the Assistant.

As it stands, the Actions on Google console does not give any visual special considerations for Smart Home projects, so it will still look for things like actions and pronunciation. But if you can sync your devices using the app, then you will see that your Smart Home action is recognized.